# How to check the status of and enable HD Voice on a Galaxy S4?

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

I would like to know if HD Voice is enabled on my device. If it's not, I would like to enable it. There used to be a very simple way of doing this by dialing `*#0011#` and then following instructions given [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287992). Unfortunately it appears that Samsung has patched this up now in the latest software version so it's no longer an option. My device is a Galaxy S4 Plus (GT-I9506) running Android 4.3.

So now that this is no longer an option, what options do I have to check the status of and to enable HD Voice on my device (in case it's disabled)?

Comment: Note: This device is not rooted. It runs stock Android from Samsung.